# How do you disabled a bootstrap form field?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

What I mean is.

I've implemented a bootstrap datetimepicker here. https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/

my question is.

if you have an input box how do you disable it and only let the inputs of the datetimepicker be valid? because the user might input an invalid format of the date.

the code below is taken here https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/#minimum-setup

code:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class='col-sm-6'>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
                    <input type='text' class="form-control" />
                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function () {
                $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker();
            });
        </script>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

You should be able to use the **readonly** attribute on the text input, and jQuery will still be able to edit its contents.

```
<input type='text' id='foo' readonly>
```

Comment: The values "true" and "false" are not allowed on boolean attributes. http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#boolean-attributes

Comment: it still doesn't work.

I don't know why

the calendar won't pop up

Answer (score 4):

You need to add the `disabled` attribute to your field, like so:

```
<input type='text' class="form-control" disabled="true">
```

And technically, these other options will also work fine:

**value of 'disabled'**

```
<input type='text' class="form-control" disabled="disabled">
```

or

**no value at all, just the name of the attribute**

```
<input type='text' class="form-control" disabled>
```